# SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio Toolbox Add-ons?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Apologies in advance, I'm entering virgin territory here (yeehaw), since I don't have much SQL Server reporting experience to-date.

My team is looking for new report add-ins (charts, advanced grids, etc.) for SQL Server BI Studio. Based on what I heard from Telerik, this is not something they support; I'm going to look at Infragistic's offerings next.

We would like these additional toolbox widgets to support HTML, PDF, and Excel report output formats.

Does anyone know of a vendor that supports BI studio directly? Or, would *any* form of .NET add-in components be compatible with SQL Server BI Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the magic word here is "extension". The SSRS architecture supports different types of modular extensions: data processing extensions, rendering extensions, and data delivery extensions. Aspose is one vendor that sells extensions for SSRS. This article provides a good summary: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163840.aspx .